# Receiving an error for a SharePoint Online List when trying to edit or create a List View

Tags: listview, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I've been working on a SharePoint Online list for a while now, and creating and editing List Views has never been an issue for me. All of a sudden, I'm now receiving the "An unexpected error has occurred" screen whenever I try to create or edit a List View. I don't have this issue with newly created lists, so I'm assuming it's a list-specific issue. Anyone have ideas on how I can troubleshoot? I've resorted to creating a new list and migrating all the data from the previous list. Thanks.

[image: The Error Screen]

Answer (score 0):

Does the problem also show when You even create a very simple view(like only ID column)? Do You have a lot of items in the list? Does this list have any customization? Like new fields or content types? Or maybe calculated fields? If possible You could first remove those columns and then check. Just be aware that all the data from those columns might be lost so best first do a backup. Otherwise if You don't wish to experiment the best options are: opening a ticket to MS or/and creating similar list and migrate data between them with PowerShell. Just keep in mind that If You are using versions history on the list, by simply moving items from one list to other all versioning data will be lost.